# Scene builder with css stylesheets needs to reload stylesheet to take changes

Tags: css, javafx, scenebuilder

I have a java fxml file with some controls in it. I want to change the style of them by using my custom css file. So I use Scene Builder and loaded the css file. It worked. But when I make changes on the css the controls on the scene builder do not respond to them. Furthermore reverting (deleting or commenting out) the changes on the css file and reloading it on the fxml through scenebuilder results in making changes to the style, the ones I had commented out or deleted. Does it use any cache, should I close and reload scene builder?

Answer (score 0):

I have done some javaFX(1.x 2.x 8.x) applications without scene builder before. Today I started to use it (GLUON JavaFX Scene Builder 8.0.0) just to get what is it, because have some more javaFX tasks.

I found similar problem. I spend two hours just to attach css file to simple GridPane, and cannot do this :(. I opened my recent project fxml, and builder cannot open it, while I remove project specific import from it... (It shows error and exceptions stack trace, so I spend some time to found out why it occurs). After I fix that, my old project FXML opened scene and applied style from css (there were just colors, no images or other resources was used).

Every time I changed css - scene builder shows that it found changes, but not render them... cool, right? Even though I preview from menu.

Total: Every time you change css you should reopen fxml.